# How to instantiate abstract class c#?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, abstract

I want to implement a mini market program . 
there is a abstract class named (Goods) and two derived classes from it (dry and cold goods).
How to add some items after that ? (eggs , milk,rice...etc)

Comment: Just inherit them from `DryGoods` or `ColdGoods`? Can you [edit] the question to show the classes you have and how you want to use the others (eggs, milk etc)

Comment: I have another classes (refrigerator) , (shelves) and (cart) 
I want to use the items to put them on the shelves or in the refrigerator. and make a winform to show the items , put them in the cart and checkout, like customers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't instantiate an abstract class. It's sole purpose is to act as a base class.  Your Eggs, Milk, Rice class must derive from the Goods and implement the functionality, as shown below:

```
public abstract class Goods 
{

}

public class DryGoods : Goods
{

}

public class ColdGoods : Goods
{

}
```

You can then have the more primitive items inheriting from Dry or Cold goods.

```
public class Egg : DryGoods
{

}

public class Milk : ColdGoods
{

}
```

Alternatively if you don't need the `Milk` or `Egg` as light weight classes (Or transferable objects) you could just use the derived `DryGoods` or `ColdGoods` types directly and have a `GoodsType` property:

```
DryGoods egg = new DryGoods();
egg.GoodsType = DryGoods.Egg;

ColdGoods milk = new ColdGoods();
milk.GoodsType = ColdGoods.Milk;
```

Comment: `DryGoods` and `ColdGoods ` should probably be abstract too, not for the sake of the code, but for the sake of business logic.

Comment: If were you, I create some instance of DryGoods and ColdGoods instead create new Entity.

Comment: If I make objects from derived classes , then what is the use of (GoodsType) ?

Comment: @Saja - I added it in as an alternative (If you didn't want the entities Milk, Eggs etc).  It's simply a design preference.

Answer (score 4):

Look, you have one abstract base class:

```
public abstract class Good { }
```

And there you have your Named classes:

```
public class Egg : Good { }

public class Milk : Good { }

public class Rice : Good { }
```

You can now add Properties and Methods to the base class Good.

You can now also add Properties and Methods to the Named classes Egg, Milk, and Rice :)

You now can also have multiple Eggs, Milk and Rice, if you rename `Goods` to `Good`:

```
var allGoods = new List<Good>();

var eggs = new Egg[16];
allGoods.Add(eggs);

var milk = new Milk[64];
allGoods.Add(milk);

var rice = new Rice[64];
allGoods.Add(rice);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to make object of subclass and using that object of subclass you can set the values. You can't instantiate an abstract class. You can use it as a base class only..

Comment: thank you , where should I make the objects ? 
in the WinForm implementation?

Comment: in the .cs file it has. You should make an object in sub class.